# How to join two tables first then join to another table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a DB2 database and I have to join three tables. I would like to join first two tables and after joining firs two tables, I would like to join the joined table to another third table. I tried using left join but couldn't find a result as I expected. I tried the following:

```
select AFJKAR as "ELR_Elig_Redirect_SchdID",
       AFEZAM as "Priority",
       AFTSAS as "ELC_Status",
       AFT7CE as "ELC_From_Date",
       AFT8CE as "ELC_Thru_Date",
       AFTTAS as "ELC_Redirect_Action", 
       AFJLAR as "GPI_List",
       AIZAHA as "GPI_List_ID",
       AILUIG as "GPI_Number",
       AICXHG as "GPI_From_Date",
       AICYHG as "GPI_Thru_Date",
       SUEFC4 as "GPI_ID",
      SUB4T3 as "Drug_Name"
from CLMPRDFIL.RCELCP as RCE
left join CLMPRDFIL.RCGP2P as RCG on RCE.AFJLAR = RCG.AIZAHA 
left join CLMPRDFIL.RCGPIP as RCGP on RCG.AIZAHA = RCGP.SUEFC4;
```

Basically, I would like to join *RCE* and *RCGP2P* tables first. After joining this, I would like to join it by *RCGPIP*.

Comment: Your code should work.  Please provide sample data and desired results.  Explain what you expect as well.

Comment: There is no *first*.Join is an operator, connecting two tables, or table expressions. Resulting in yet another table expression.

Comment: "I would like to join first two tables..." -- As @wildplasser says SQL is a *declarative* language, not an *imperative* one. You specify what you need, and the SQL engine produces it. You may have some control on the execution plan, but in the end the engine decides how to run the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a corresponding optimization profile / guideline for this.
[Optimization profiles and guidelines](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0024522.html).
You may specify the desired join order there, if you believe, that you may achieve better performance with particular join order.
Note, that you should try to collect statistics on these tables first to make the Db2 optimizer use correct join order. For example, try to create a statistical view on first 2 tables using their join keys and collect statistics on it. Look at the access plan of your original query afterwards to check, if you get desired join order.